# How do I merge multiple video-only mp4 files with corresponding audio-only mp4 files using ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I have a bunch of video- and audio-only mp4 files and would like to script the merging of both files. But here's the thing, there are multiple video and audio files which are separately indicated by either (Video) or (Audio) in the file names.

This is how I've been doing it manually:

```
ffmpeg -i "Videofile (Video).mp4" -i "Audiofile (Audio).mp4" -preset fast -crf 1 "Output file Name.mp4"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat - << EOS > myVideoAudioMergerScript 
#!/bin/bash

for file in *\(Video\).mp4; do
     baseName=${file%\(*} 
     #echo baseName=$baseName 
      echo ffmpeg -i \"$f\" -i \"${baseName}(Audio).mp4\" -preset fast -crf ${baseName% }_VideoAudio.mp4
done

chmod +x myVideoAudioMergerScript
```

Will get you started. Once your satisfied that the `echo` output looks correct, you can either remove the `echo` or just pipe the output to a shell, i.e.

```
 myVideoAudioMergerScript | bash
```

I suppose some software package thought including space chars and `()` (parens) in filenames was a good idea, but it's adds to the complexity of scripting a solution AND requires that you dbl-quote any variable that uses those names.

I don't have an easy way to test this, so if you need help, update your question with exact text of error messages/filenames, etc and use the `{}` tool on mouse-selected text to give proper formatting as `code/data/output/fileName/statusMsg/errMsg`.

Comment: Added the `cat ... > myVideoAudioMergerScript ; chmod ...` thing. ...... You must execute this  from a linux terminal where you have `cd`ed into the directory that has you split `.mp4` files.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll give it a go and let you know how it goes.